# Setting the end of the match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=b|suffix=c] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]
```

And I would like to get the value of the prefix of *TITLE*, which is **a**.

I have tried it with `(?<=TITLE|)(?<=prefix=).*?(?=]|\|)` and that seems to work but that gives me also the prefix of *STORENAME* (**b**). So if `[TITLE|prefix=a]` will be missing in the string, I'll have the wrong value.

So I need to set the end of the match with `]` that belongs to `[TITLE`. Please notice that this string is dynamic. So it could be `[TITLE|suffix=x|prefix=y]` as well.

```js
const regex = "[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=b|suffix=c] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]".match(/(?<=TITLE|)(?<=prefix=).*?(?=]|\|)/);
console.log(regex);
```

Comment: would be awesome if you made it a snippet... would be a lot easier for others to debug ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=TITLE(?:\|suffix=[^\]|]+)?\|prefix=)[^\]|]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eYk3jw/1). Details:

- `(?<=TITLE(?:\|suffix=[^\]|]+)?\|prefix=)` - a location in string immediately preceded with `TITLE|prefix|` or `TITLE|suffix=...|prefix|`
- `[^\]|]+` - one or more chars other than `]` and `|`.

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=b|suffix=c] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]', '[TITLE|suffix=s|prefix=a]'];
for (let s of texts) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.match(/(?<=TITLE(?:\|suffix=[^\]|]+)?\|prefix=)[^\]|]+/)[0]);
}
```

Comment: So what if the string would be `[TITLE|suffix=s|prefix=a]`?

Comment: @Proseller Added to the answer.

Comment: Great. Just what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a capturing group

```
\[TITLE\|(?:[^|=\]]*=[^|=\]]*\|)*prefix=([^|=\]]*)[^\]]*]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[TITLE\|` Match `[TITLE|`
- `(?:\w+=\w+\|)*` Repeat 0+ occurrences wordchars `=` wordchars and `|`
- `prefix=` Match literally
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars
- `[^\]]*` Match any char except `]`
- `]` Match the closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Fg1ZE/1)

```js
const regex = /\[TITLE\|(?:\w+=\w+\|)*prefix=(\w+)[^\]]*\]/g;
const str = `[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=b|suffix=c] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]
[TITLE|suffix=x|prefix=y]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Or with a negated character class instead of `\w`

```
\[TITLE\|(?:[^|=\]]*=[^|=\]]*\|)*prefix=([^|=\]]*)[^\]]*]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cvwMIQ/1)